# Tests for normed vector

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have many vectors $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^p:||a||=1,1\leq i \leq n$. I would like to test whether the $a_i$'s are randomly spread out on $S^{p-1}$ (the $p$ variate unit circle). Can anyone point to a test for that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How is what you're wanting to do different from a goodness-of-fit test that your data come from the uniform measure on the $S^{p-1}$ sphere?

Comment: Could work. How would you test this in practice?

Comment: I offer a diagnostic plot at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7984/919.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transform your data points to spherical coordinates so that you get $p-1$ angles. Your null hypothesis is equivalent to the fact that those angles are independent and uniformly distributed. So you can do a goodness of fit test.

Now there is the complication that you have a $p-1$-dimensional distribution. [This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-7/issue-4/Multivariate-Generalizations-of-the-Wald-Wolfowitz-and-Smirnov-Two-Sample/10.1214/aos/1176344722.full) shows a multidimensional version of the Smirnov statistic that may come in handy. Otherwise, another idea that comes to my mind woud be to scale the angles to $(0,1)$, apply the inverse erf function and do a test for [multivariate normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests).

**Erratum:** it is not true that the angles will be uniform as shown in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-in-the-3-d-unit-ball/30622#30622). One angle is uniform between $0$ and $2\pi$, and the *cosine* of the others is uniform between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: in your second paragraph, by scaling the angles to 0-1, you mean dividing each component of the p-1 dimensional angle vector by pi?

Comment: Depends on your parametrization. For example in 3D, spherical coordinates are usually given as an angle between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ (longitude) and another one between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ (latitude). For longitude add $\pi$ and divide by $2\pi$ and for latitude add $\pi/2$ and divide by $\pi$.