# Conditional Expectation / Estimator Confusion

Tags: self-study, expected-value, conditional-expectation, estimators

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3 \sim N(0, d^2)$ and $T = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2.$

I have an estimator for $d$, $$\hat{d} = \frac{\sqrt{T\ 2\pi}}{4},$$
and another estimator for $d$, $$\tilde{d} = \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\pi / 2}\ \left(|X_1| + |X_2| + |X_3|\right).$$

I need to show that $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{d} | T) = \hat{d}$ and that $\mathbb{E}(|X_1| | T) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{T}$.

I'm not clear how conditioning the expectation on $T$ changes things and how it affects the computation of expectation.

---

*(The following edit was attempted by the OP in an answer, I'm updating the question on their behalf.)*

I'm mostly confused about how to write out $E[d\sim | T]$ or $E[|X1| | T]$ and begin to work through the algebra.

Comment: Given that $\hat{d}$ is a function of $T$, it is evident that both expectations are (non-trivial) functions of $T$. If you did *not* condition on $T$ and took an expectation, it would be nonsensical for $T$ to enter in the formula, wouldn't it?  I realize this might not help one's intuition, but surely it shows a clear difference between conditioning on $T$ and not conditioning on it.

Comment: As a hint, one powerful (and historically early) approach uses geometrical reasoning. Upon recognizing that, conditional on $T$, the vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is uniformly distributed on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{T}$, it's easy to see that the two parts of the question are very closely related (the second part immediately answers the first part) and the $1/2$ in the second part is the average height of a random point on the upper hemisphere of a unit sphere. This is illustrated at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977 and further discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22764

Comment: I'm unable to edit my original question. I'm mostly confused about how to write out E[d~ | T] or E[|X1| | T] and begin to work through the algebra

Comment: @xardox Of course you cannot edit the question: you are not klingzon! The two accounts use different identifiers. If both you and klingzon verify you are the same person, a moderator can merge your accounts and then you'll be fine.

Comment: @gung Oh yes, totally!! Good observation.

Answer (score 2):

Since this looks like homework, or exercise I will skim through the solution.

Let's write

$$f_{X_i|T}(x_i | t) = \frac{f_{X_i, T}(x_i, t)}{f_T(t)}.$$

The joint distribution $f_{X_i, T}(x_i, t)$ is the product of a Gaussian $(0, d^2)$ and a $\chi^2(2)$ (the post does not specify that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent, but I will take it for granted):

$$f_{X_i, T}(x_i, t) \propto \exp\left\{-\frac{x_i^2}{2d^2} \right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{t-x_i^2}{2d^2}\right\},$$

which (miraculously) simplifies to

$$f_{X_i, T}(x_i, t) \propto \exp\left\{-\frac{t}{2d^2}\right\}.$$

From here this is quite easy because we realize that the numerator does not depend on $x_i$ so the distribution of $x_i$ given $t$ is uniform. The boundaries for $x_i$ given $t$ are $-\sqrt{t}$ and $+\sqrt{t}$ by construction, so the expected value $E(|X_i| | T=t)$ is

$$ 2\int_0^{\sqrt{t}} \frac{x_i}{2\sqrt{t}} dx_i = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t}.$$

The expected value of a sum is the sum of the expected values, so getting $E(\tilde{d} | T=t)$ is piece of cake.

**EDIT:** Following @whuber's comment, here is how I got $f_{X_i|T}(x_i | t)$. I will assume $i=1$ for the sake of the argument. Let's define $Z = X_2^2 + X_3^2$, which is a scaled $\chi^2(2)$, *i.e* with 2 degrees of freedom.

The joint density of $(X_1, Z)$ is the product of their densities because they depend on different variables, so $\propto \exp\left\{-\frac{x_1^2}{2d^2} \right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{z}{2d^2}\right\}$. Now we use the change of variable $(X_1, Z) \rightarrow (X_1, X_1^2 + Z = T)$. The Jacobian of the inverse transformation is 1, so $f_{X_1|T}(x_1 | t) \propto \exp\left\{-\frac{x_1^2}{2d^2} \right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{t-x_1^2}{2d^2}\right\}$.

Comment: Umm... I'm pretty sure that $T$ has three degrees of freedom, not two. Not that it matters--everything is conditioned on $T$.  But maybe I misunderstand the notation. All the work depends on justifying that assertion about the joint distribution.

Comment: @whuber absolutely. My bad. By the way, I like your geometric answer (to the duplicate of that question) better :D

Comment: @whuber actually thinking about it, I stick to my point (see the edit). Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Now I'm convinced :-).