# Computing conditional expectations

Tags: conditional-expectation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional Expectation / Estimator Confusion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41038/conditional-expectation-estimator-confusion)

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3 \sim N(0, d^2)$ and $T = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2.$

I have an estimator for $d$, $$\hat{d} = \frac{\sqrt{T\ 2\pi}}{4},$$
and another estimator for $d$, $$\tilde{d} = \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\pi / 2}\ \left(|X_1| + |X_2| + |X_3|\right).$$

I need to show that $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{d} | T) = \hat{d}$ and that $\mathbb{E}(|X_1| | T) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{T}$.

I'm mostly confused about how to proceed with the algebra to compute the expectations.  I have never had to compute E[estimator | something] before