# Compute the mean of normalized norms of linear transformations of Gaussian random vectors

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, linear-algebra

if $M$ is a $m\times n$ constant matrix and $\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$, then does $$\mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}}\left[\frac{\lVert M\eta\rVert}{\lVert\eta\rVert}\right]$$
exist? Also, let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n_{\ne 0}$ be an arbitrary non-zero vector. Is it possible to compute the maximum (or at least to find a tight upper-bound) over all $x$, of the quantity $$\mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}}\left[\frac{\lVert M(x+\lVert x\rVert \eta)-Mx\rVert}{\lVert Mx \rVert}\right]=\lVert x\rVert\mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}}\left[\frac{\lVert M \eta\rVert}{\lVert Mx \rVert}\right]$$

Comment: This function is bounded: it represents the amount by which the linear operator represented by $M$ changes the length of its argument $\eta$ and no linear operator can change lengths by infinite amounts.  This is also a hint concerning how you can obtain an upper bound of the expectation.  In the second part of the question, separately consider the cases where $M$ has nontrivial kernel and where it does not.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algebraic answer. Each of these steps has a geometric interpretation that I'm sure could give you a simpler overall explanation for someone who thinks that way....

Take the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $M$ as $M = U \Sigma V^T$. Here $U \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and $V \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ are orthogonal matrices ($V^T V = V V^T = I$), and $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ has $\Sigma_{ii} = \sigma_i$ (the singular values) and all other entries are zero.

Now, 
$$
\lVert M \eta \rVert^2
= \lVert U \Sigma V^T \eta \rVert^2
= \eta^T V \Sigma^T U^T U \Sigma V^T \eta
= \eta^T V \Sigma^T \Sigma V^T \eta
= \lVert \Sigma V^T \eta \rVert^2
.$$

Because $\eta \sim \mathcal N(0, I)$,
we have that $V^T \eta \sim \mathcal N(V^T 0, V^T V) = \mathcal N(0, I)$.
Also notice that
$$
\lVert V^T \eta \rVert^2
= \eta^T V V^T \eta
= \eta^T \eta
= \lVert \eta \rVert^2
.$$
So we can do a change of variables to $V^T \eta = X = A W$,
with $X \sim \mathcal N(0, I)$
and
$A = \lVert X \rVert \sim \chi_1(n)$
and $W = X / A$ is uniform on the unit sphere $\{ x : \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$:
$$
\mathbf E_{\eta \sim \mathcal N(0, I)}\left[ \frac{\lVert M \eta \rVert}{\lVert \eta \rVert} \right]
= \mathbf E_{A, W}\left[ \frac{\lVert \Sigma A W \rVert}{\lVert A W \rVert} \right]
= \mathbf E_{A, W}\left[ \frac{\lVert \Sigma W \rVert}{\lVert W \rVert} \right]
= \mathbf E_{W}\left[ \lVert \Sigma W \rVert \right]
.$$
This is not trivial to evaluate exactly in general.
But we can find an easy upper bound via [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):
$$
\mathbf E_{W}\left[ \lVert \Sigma W \rVert \right]
\le \sqrt{\mathbf E_{W}\left[ \lVert \Sigma W \rVert^2 \right]}
= \sqrt{ \mathbf E_{W}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{\min(m, n)} \sigma_i^2 W_i^2 \right] }
= \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{\min(m, n)} \sigma_i^2 \,\mathbf E_{W}\left[ W_i^2 \right] }
.$$
We have that $\mathbf E_W[ W_i^2 ] = 1/n$ as shown e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22764/covariance-matrix-of-uniform-spherical-distribution),
and 
$\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{\min(m, n)} \sigma_i^2 }$ is exactly the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm),
$\lVert M \rVert_F = \sqrt{ \sum_{ij} M_{ij}^2 }$.
Thus
$$
\mathbf E_{\eta \sim \mathcal N(0, I)}\left[ \frac{\lVert M \eta \rVert}{\lVert \eta \rVert} \right]
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \lVert M \rVert_F
.$$

---

Your second question is slightly different:
$$
\lVert x\rVert \mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \frac{\lVert M \eta\rVert}{\lVert Mx \rVert}\right]
= 
\frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lVert M x \rVert} \mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \lVert M \eta\rVert \right]
.$$
Observing that $M \eta \sim \mathcal N(0, M M^T)$,
this question reduces to finding the expected norm of a multivariate normal.
A quick Jensen bound as before gives
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \lVert M \eta\rVert \right]
  &\le \sqrt{ \mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \lVert M \eta\rVert^2 \right] }
\\&= \sqrt{ \mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \eta^T M^T M \eta \right] }
\\&= \sqrt{ \mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \operatorname{tr}\left( \eta \eta^T M^T M \right) \right] }
\\&= \sqrt{ \operatorname{tr}\left( \mathbf{E}_{\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}\left[ \eta \eta^T \right] M^T M \right) }
\\&= \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(M^T M)}
\\&= \lVert M \rVert_F
.\end{align}
The (very ugly) exact solution is also available in the links from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144893/what-is-the-expected-norm-mathbb-e-lvert-x-rvert-for-a-multivariate-normal) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-normally-distribu).
(One could also maybe derive the exact answer for the first question with these techniques as well.)

Comment: I think at least one of your upper bounds can be transformed to an exact bound (maximum). I’ll have a look at it next week.