# Proof that the floor of an exponential random variable is a geometric variable

Tags: self-study, density-function, exponential-distribution, geometric-distribution

For any real number $x$,$[x]$ represents the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.
If $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean $1/K$,show that $[X]$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $p = 1 - e^{-K}$.

How can I prove this?

I know what geometric and exponential distributions are!

Comment: This looks like a textbook problem. If so, it needs a `self-study` tag and the rules for [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) need to 2b followed.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof or just hints to help you get there?  We are only suppose to apply hints to self study questions.

Comment: The first half of my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136956/919 provides a thorough and rigorous proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple hints:
\begin{align*}
P([X] = x) &= P(x \le X < x+1) \tag{logic} \\
&= P(x < X \le x+1) \tag{$X$ is a continuous rv}  
\end{align*}
for any non-negative integer $x$.