# Generate random numbers with linear distribution

Tags: r, probability, distributions

How can I generate random floating-point numbers, the probability function of which is linear? Suppose I can generate uniform randoms.[image: Distribution plot]

Plot is example of linear distribution. f - probability density, x - random value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating Beta distribution from Uniform distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169293/generating-beta-distribution-from-uniform-distribution)

Comment: What is f1 in your plot? How do you ensure that f1 and f2 are consistent?

Comment: A pure triangular distribution can be generated as the sum of two independent uniforms. Try to generalize from that.

Comment: @user777, no. I'm not interested in beta distribution.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, what he has drawn is **not** a beta distribution! Voting to stay open.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The point I'm making is that the inverse sampling transform is a very general way to get deviates of arbitrary distributions from uniform deviates. The "beta distribution" portion of that question is entirely incidental to the answer.

Comment: Yes, but for triangular distributions there are some other methods as well. The simplest one being sum <of two uniforms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many methods. Here are a few.

- You could use [rejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) ("accept-reject") with a uniform envelope.
- could could use the [inverse cdf method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Definition) on the density, by working out the cdf and inverting it $X=F^{-1}(U)$
- You could split into a uniform and a triangular part (i.e. a [finite mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) of the two). The triangular part can be generated in any of several ways (e.g. the $\max$ of two uniforms, or using the inverse cdf method, ...) and then scaled to the right interval, and the uniform is trivial (simply scaled to the right interval).
- if $x_1$ is positive, you could treat as triangular on $(0,x_2)$ and then use rejection in the case where it's below $x_1$. This will work pretty well if $x_1/x_2$ is small (a good bit less than half, say).
- you could use the [ziggurat method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm).

There are a number of other approaches. The choice between them would depend on considerations such as how much convenience vs speed matters (if you only need a few thousand values, speed probably doesn't matter much; if you need to use it many many times with potentially long runs, there it may matter much more).

Answer (score 9):

This reminds me of another post about a linear pdf which had functional form:

$$ h(x) = \frac{1+\alpha x}{2}, \quad \quad  x \in [-1,1], \quad \alpha\in[-1,1] $$

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/pdfmix.png))</sub>

I called this an 'acute linear' distribution, or a cute linear distribution.

If $X_1\sim \text{Triangular}(-1,1,1)$ and $X_2\sim \text{Uniform}(-1,1)$ are independent, then $$X\sim \alpha  X_1+(1-\alpha ) X_2$$  ... has a cute Linear distribution.

**Pseudo-random number generation**

The cdf (within the domain of support) is:  $$H = \frac{1}{4} (x+1) (\alpha  (x-1)+2)$$

The inverse cdf is: $$x = H^{-1}(u) = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha ^2-2 \alpha +4 \alpha  u+1}-1}{\alpha }$$

Replacing $u$ with a pseudo-random drawing from $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ then yields a pseudo-random drawing from the above cute linear pdf $h(x)$.

If you wish to change the scale, or shift it, you can transform the data $X_{data}$ you generate .. e.g. $Y = b + c X_{data}$ ... which should be able to generate the richness of whatever structure you desire (might require a little bit of playing around, depending on what you are holding fixed).