# How to convert a Gaussian distribution random variables into a Rayleigh?

Tags: distributions, matlab, random-generation

`X=randn(2000,1)` Gaussian random variable with mean = 0 and variance = 1 
how to transform $X$ to $Y$ that is a Rayleigh distributed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why exactly would you like to generate Rayleigh distributed values using normal samples?

There are two possible approaches. First, you can use [inverse transform sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337). If $U$ is uniformly distributed in $(0, 1)$, then

$$
Y=\sigma\sqrt{-2 \ln(1 - U)}
$$

follows a Rayleigh distribution. You can recall that if $F$ is a cumulative distribution function and $X \sim F$, then $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed, so you can take $U = F(X)$ and using normally distributed $X$ transform it to uniform and then transform it to Rayleigh, but this is not very efficient since you could simply start with uniform $U$.

Second, you can use the property that $Y \sim \mathcal{R}(\sigma)$ is Rayleigh distributed if $Y = \sqrt{X^2 + Z^2}$, where both $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, so if you have *two* normally distributed variables, you can use them to obtain Rayleigh distributed samples.

As usually, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) has a nice article about Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: I want to generate Rayleigh distributed variables only from Gaussian distributed variable X that I obtained from the previous operation on my project .

Comment: @hamzehghanem so the first approach is for you or you can use the second approach to obtain half the number of the samples.

Comment: how i could use the second approach if i  have only X (one one Gaussian variables ) ?

Comment: @hamzehghanem you have 2000 values, so take first 1000 as X and second 1000 as Z, square them, add and take square root, and you'll end up with 1000 Rayleigh samples.

Comment: but I want to generate 2000 points Rayleigh from 2000 points  Gaussian ?

Comment: @hamzehghanem so use the first method...

Comment: +1.  Note that you can obtain 2,000 iid values of $U$ from 2,000 iid Normal variates by various methods described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117689 :-)