# Can we sample from the wrapped normal distribution and evaluate the density of the sample simultaneously?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, density-function, circular-statistics, measure-theory

In a computer program (written in C++), given $x\in[0,1)$ and $\sigma>0$, I need to sample $y$ from the wrapped normal distribution $\mathcal W_{x,\:\sigma^2}$ with mean $x$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and evaluate the density $q$ of $\mathcal W_{x,\:\sigma^2}$ at $y$ at the same time.

If $\varphi_{\sigma^2}$ denotes the density of the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $$\psi_{\sigma^2}(y):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\varphi_{\sigma^2}(k+y)\;\;\;\text{for }y\in\mathbb R,$$ then $$q(y):=\psi_{\sigma^2}(y-x)\;\;\;\text{for }y\in[0,1)$$ is the density of $\mathcal W_{x,\:\sigma^2}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

> We can sample $y$ by drawing $\xi\sim\mathcal N_{0,\:1}$, setting $z:=x+\sigma\xi$ and $y:=z-\lfloor z\rfloor$. But now I would need to evaluate $q(y)$ separately.
>
> So, my question is: Can we somehow sample $y$ in a clever way such that we obtain $q(y)$ as a byproduct? If not, how should we evaluate $q(y)$ (the problematic thing being that it's an infinite sum)?

Comment: It's an infinite sum, but for $\sigma$ not much larger than $1$, it will converge pretty quickly.  Consider $\sigma = 2$ and $y = 1/2$; the 10th term is $\sim 2.5\times 10^{-6}$, and subsequent terms decrease by more than a factor of $10$.  With $\sigma = 1$, the sixth term is $\sim 10^{-7}$ and the seventh $\sim 3\times 10^{-10}$, for example.

Comment: @jbowman So, should I sum from $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ adding up $a_k:=\varphi_{\sigma^2}(y+k)$ and $b_k:=\varphi_{\sigma^2}(y-k)$ and stop once $a_k<\epsilon$ for some suitable $\epsilon$ (maybe $\epsilon=10^{-6}$?)? Or should I check $b_k$ as well?

Comment: When $\sigma$ is only a little larger than $1,$ for all practical computational purposes this density is *uniform:* see the last method at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117711/919.  For smaller $\sigma,$ as @jbowman indicates, the sum converges *very* rapidly.  It is a theta function; some software includes procedures to evaluate it (buried, for instance, in the KS test).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. The $\sigma$ I've got in mind is smaller than $1$, e.g. $\sigma=0.01$.

Comment: Then you can evaluate the density anywhere with a single term of the series!  (At many points--more than about $0.05$ from the mean--you don't need any terms at all, because the density is practically zero there.)

Comment: @whuber Well, I guess you're right. Didn't thought about that (+1)! However, I guess I can't obtain the density simultaneously with sampling or is there a possibility?

Comment: I don't see why sampling wouldn't work as it always does.  Just estimate the density using a circular method so that values near the endpoints $\{0,1\}$ are treated appropriately.  Indeed, you may safely shift all values (modulo $1$) to make any single observation the new origin and treat the problem as estimating a density from a Normal sample.  The chance of erring is far less than $10^{-100}.$ But why is there any need? You already know what distribution you are sampling from!

Comment: @whuber I need the density for an importance sampling correction. I don't understand your suggestion. Do you say that I should sample $y$ as usual and then compute density as described in my first comment (where it is most probably sufficient to only take the first sumand $k=0$ for my choice of $\sigma$)? Or what do you mean by a "circular method"? How would that be different from what I've described in the question?

Comment: In `R`, just apply this function to a vector of the data: `function(x) {y <- (x-x[1]+1/2) %% 1; c((mean(y)+x[1]-1/2) %% 1, sd(y))})`  Assuming $\sigma \ll 1$ ($\sigma \lt 1/10$ should work well), it will provide an accurate estimate of the mean and sd.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input, but I need it in C++.

Comment: I'm sure you can write the C++ code that implements this very simple calculation!  If not, SE is the place to ask about it.

Comment: @whuber Of course, I could, but since I never used `R` I'm not able to fully understand your code ;)

Comment: About the only explanation it needs for someone familiar with `C` syntax is that `%%` reduces a value modulo $1.$

Comment: How about https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268443292_Efficient_Evaluation_of_the_Probability_Density_Function_of_a_Wrapped_Normal_Distribution ?