# Return value from normal distribution using Bernoulli trial generator

Tags: normal-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Given a random Bernoulli trial generator, how do you return a value sampled from a normal distribution?

Came across this question in my interview prep. I thought it can be done by tuning the probability of success in the generator but I am not sure.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117689.  Given that Bernoulli trials return only zeros and ones, it's hard to see what tuning it might do.  Consider instead using it to generate binary sequences, because from there it's easy to obtain a uniform value in $[0,1)$ and you're off and running (search "Box Muller").

Comment: If you generate $n=100$ observations from $\mathsf{Binom}(100, 1/2)$ you will have 100 observations that are nearly $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=25,\sigma=5),$ (except rounded to integers). In R, `x = rbinom(100, 100, .5);  mean(x); sd(x); shapiro.test(x)$p.val` returns $\bar X \approx 50, S \approx 5,$ and P-value > 5% for the normality test.

Comment: For some historically clever solutions, see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2245712?seq=1.  I believe this may be the article in which Stigler describes Galton's dice, which had special (floating) values written on them which when summed emulated a standard Normal variate remarkably well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with random bits using an algorithm presented by C.F.F. Karney, "[Sampling exactly from a normal distribution](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6257v2)".

This algorithm involves building up uniform(0,1) random numbers one bit at a time, from left to right, using unbiased random bits, and doing comparisons with these numbers. If these comparisons succeed, this means the initial bits of a normal random number have thus been generated, so the algorithm can fill up additional digits to the right with unbiased random bits. For details on the algorithm, see the paper.

In case the "Bernoulli trial generator" outputs *biased* random bits, the algorithm can produce *unbiased* random bits from those biased bits using a *randomness extraction* technique, such as von Neumann's algorithm, Peres's iterated von Neumann method, or Zhou and Bruck's "extractor tree" (see my [note on randomness extraction](https://peteroupc.github.io/randextract.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to generate some samples and to use Central Limit Theorem. Averaging the sample data points will give you a value from Normal distribution.

Comment: Even as a practical solution this works poorly unless you generate those "samples" in a particularly clever way.  (That's what Galton's dice were all about.)

Comment: You're right. I think it'd be helpful to have this "suggested" solution and your comment here for others to see in case they think of using CLT as a potential solution.