# How does one sample from a gaussian distribution without a library?

Tags: distributions, random-generation

I am looking to write a program that generates samples from a gaussian distribution with a certain mean and standard deviation. I am not allowed to use any library except a random number generator. Is there a trivial way that one could do that? I am familiar with techniques like rejection sampling or a mcmc approach but they might not be easy to implement without a library.

Note - The reason I am asking this question on Cross Validated instead of StackOverFlow is because I am not looking for code. I am rather looking for equations that I can convert into code.

Comment: The answer depends on what computational facilities your system supports.  For instance, can you compute logarithms?  Trigonometric functions?  Assuming you can, the [Box-Muller method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Box+muller) is standard and simple.  But why are you "not allowed"?  Is this a learning exercise or an actual problem?

Comment: Note that many of the procedures and principles used to [generate uniform random variates from a Normal variate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117711/919) can be reversed to solve this problem, too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @whuber. Yes, this is an actual problem wherein I need to write code to sample from a normal distribution that doesn't build up from other libraries.

Comment: Again: what *are* you allowed?  Exactly how limited is your programming environment?

Comment: I am allowed to use standard trigonometric and logarthmic functions

Comment: Okay, then the duplicate provides some effective (and good) answers.