Custom algorithm to create a normal distribution from a uniform distribution, struggle with a parameter
I made a custom algorithm to convert a uniform distribution to a random distribution, but struggle with a parameter.
Here is the code in R:
(I'll explain the main idea and the parameters)

normal_gen1 <- function(n_inpt = 10000,
                        mean_inpt, 
                        sd_inpt, 
                        offset_proba = 0.01,
                        low_del,
                        intervl){
  rtn_v <- c()
  offset_val <- (log(0.01 * sd_inpt * (2 * pi) ** 0.5) * - 2) ** 0.5 * sd_inpt
  random_data <- runif(n = n_inpt * 2, min = 0, max = offset_val)
  cur_step <- offset_val / n_inpt
  ref_v <- seq(from = cur_step, to = offset_val, by = cur_step)
  already_v = rep(x = 0, times = length(ref_v))
  cnt = 1
  while (length(rtn_v) < n_inpt){
    cur_time <- random_data[cnt %% length(random_data)]
    cur_max_val <- (1 / (sd_inpt * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((cur_time / sd_inpt) ** 2) / 2))
    min_idx <- which.min(abs(ref_v - cur_time))
    if (already_v[min_idx] < cur_max_val * 2 - low_del){
      if (cnt %% 2 == 0){
        rtn_v <- c(rtn_v, (mean_inpt - cur_time))
      }else{
        rtn_v <- c(rtn_v, (mean_inpt + cur_time))
      }
      if (min_idx - intervl < 1){
        already_v[1:(min_idx + intervl)] = already_v[1:(min_idx + intervl)] + (1 / n_inpt)
      }else if (min_idx + intervl > length(already_v)){
        already_v[(min_idx - intervl):length(already_v)] = already_v[(min_idx - intervl):length(already_v)] + (1 / n_inpt)
      }else{
        already_v[(min_idx - intervl):(min_idx + intervl)] = already_v[(min_idx - intervl):(min_idx + intervl)] + (1 / n_inpt)
      }
    }
    if ((cnt + 1) < length(random_data)){
      cnt = cnt + 1
    }else{
      cnt = 1
    }
  }
  return(rtn_v)
}



We can run it with several mean or sd.
For example:
library("ggplot2")

x <- normal_gen1(n_inpt = 5000,
                  mean_inpt = 15,
                  sd_inpt = 0.5,
                  offset_proba = 0.01,
                  low_del = 0,
                  intervl = 0.58 * 5000)

sd(x)
mean(x)

pdf("out2.pdf")
datf <- data.frame(x = c(1:length(x)), y = sort(x))
ggplot(data = datf, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal()


Returns something like this:
[1] 0.5019585 # for sd 
[1] 15.000383

and

So, the parameter that allow the algorithm to work is intervl.
The main idea is the following:
Since we generate the normal distribution according to a uniform distribution as this one:
random_data <- runif(n = n_inpt * 2, min = 0, max = offset_val)
# offset_val is the most unlikely value to be included in  the vector representing the normal distribution

So, whenever the algorithm choose a value from random_data, we need to tell him that the closest values to the random chosen value must have their frequency increased.
The main question is how close to this value?
This question is answered by the parameter intervl (interval).
As you saw with the previous example we always multiply the number of values we want to generate (5000) by another value. And this is this value that i will reference by intervl for the following of the post.
I noticed that higher sd is, the lowest intervl is.
Intuitively, if the algorithm is more likely to include a value far from the average, the less we need to increase the frequency of the closest values to the random chosen value.
So, i made this script to find the best intervl between 0.5 to 9.
I start with sd = 0.5 and intervl = 0.58 * 5000 as a reference value and increase sd and decrease intervl.
 library("ggplot2")
rtn_datf <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
intervl_base = 0.58
for (I in seq(from = 0.5, to = 9, by = 0.1)){
  cur_sd <- sd(
    normal_gen1(n_inpt = 5000,
                  mean_inpt = 15,
                  sd_inpt = I,
                  offset_proba = 0.01,
                  low_del = 0,
                  intervl = intervl_base * 5000)
  )  
  while (abs(cur_sd - I) > 0.05){
    intervl_base = intervl_base - 0.0001
    print(intervl_base)
    cur_sd <- sd(
        normal_gen1(n_inpt = 5000,
                      mean_inpt = 15,
                      sd_inpt = I,
                      offset_proba = 0.01,
                      low_del = 0,
                      intervl = intervl_base * 5000)
      )  
  }
  rtn_datf <- rbind(rtn_datf, data.frame(I, intervl_base))
}

pdf("out.pdf")
ggplot(data = rtn_datf, mapping = aes(x = I, y = intervl_base)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_minimal()

write.table(x = rtn_datf, file = "math.csv")


The output:

(the x axis is sd)
It looks like this function:

Where x = sd
But i'm not sure, i have just noticed that it looks like 1 / ln(1 + sd) and intuitively (or randomly depending of the point of view :) ) tweaked parameters.
Is the value of intervl can be described as a function ?
If yes, what could it be ?
Many thanks!

I'm sorry, but I just can't figure out what your question is: "how close to this value" must be missing some key words.  But perhaps our thread on the inverse question of generating uniform variates from Normal ones could be of interest to you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117689.  Regardless, R supplies a function to solve your problem -- it's called qnorm -- so could you please explain what you're trying to achieve with your code?

Thanks for the feedback, i will rephrase my question.
