# Derive the distribution of the fraction ${\sum{x_i}}\Big/{\sqrt{\sum{x_i^2}}}$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Suppose ${X_i}$ follows the standard normal distributon N(0,1), what is the distribution of  $\frac{\sum{x_i}}{\sqrt{\sum{x_i^2}}}$

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: Assuming $X_i$'s are independent, the vector $\left(\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{\sum X_i^2}}\right)_{1\le i\le n}$ is uniformly distributed on the surface of a unit sphere. So you are looking for the distribution of sum of the components of this vector. Where do you need this?

Comment: That this is a uniform distribution on the sphere is shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977.  The distribution of the components is derived at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916.  These two threads together therefore (fully) answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can rewrite $\sum x_i^2 = \bar{x}^2 + \sum (x_i -\bar{x})^2$.

Note that the terms $n\bar{x}^2$ and $\sum (x_i -\bar{x})^2$ are independent chi-squared distributed variables.

Then you can rewrite $Y = \frac{\sum{x_i}}{\sqrt{\sum{x_i^2}}}$ as

$$\begin{array}{}
Y^2 &= &\frac{\left(\sum{x_i}\right)^2}{{\sum{x_i^2}}}\\
&=& \frac{n^2\bar{x}^2}{\bar{x}^2+{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}}\\
&=& \frac{n}{1/n+{\left(\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right)/(n\bar{x}^2)}}\\
\end{array}$$

And this term in the denominator ${\left(\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right)/(n\bar{x}^2)}$ follows an F-distribution

So we have that $n/Y^2-1/n$ follows a F-distribution.

Possibly this can be simplified further (edit: and as Henry noted in the comments you can 'turn it into' a beta distribution. Or... $Y^2$ follows a beta distribution.)

Comment: $Y$ seems to be a symmetric Beta distribution relocated and rescaled to have mean $0$ and variance $1$ (might that be called a *standardised symmetric Beta distribution*?)

Comment: @Henry you are right you can simplify it to a beta distribution. The beta distribution and F-distribution [are related](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Properties_and_related_distributions). My answer was mostly to give the hint to rewrite $\sum x_i^2 = \bar{x}^2 + \sum (x_i -\bar{x})^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Some empirical assertions if there are $n$ terms and $Y_n = \frac{\sum_1^n{X_i}}{\sqrt{\sum_1^n{X_i^2}}}$  with the $X_i$ iid $N(0,1)$:

- $Y_n$ has expectation $0$ and variance $1$
- $Y_n$ has support on $[-\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}]$ (unless $n=1$, in which case the support is just $\{-1,1\}$)
- The density for $Y_n$ on its support is proportional to $(n-y^2)^{(n-3)/2}$
- In particular if $n=3$ this is a uniform distribution; if $n=4$ it is a Wigner semicircle distribution; if $n=2$ it is a version of the arcsine distribution
- $\frac{Y_n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac12$ has a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{n-1}{2}$; perhaps $Y_n$ could be called a *standardised symmetric Beta distribution*
- As $n$ increases, the distribution of $Y_n$ converges to a standard normal distribution
- If $Z_{i,n} = \frac{{X_i}}{\sqrt{\sum_1^n{X_i^2}}}$  with the $X_i$ iid $N(0,1)$ then $Y_n =\sum_1^n Z_{i,n}$ and, as StubbornAtom commented,
  the vector $\mathbf Z_{n}$ is uniformly distributed on the surface of a unit hypersphere. $Z_{i,n}$ has the same distribution as $\frac{Y_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, so with mean $0$ and variance $\frac1n$ supported on $[-1,1]$

Comment: This density $(n-y^2)^{(n-3)/2}$ is not of a beta distribution, but the density of a variable that is the square root of a variable that follows a beta distribution. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution#Relation_to_the_Beta_distribution

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus it does have a relocated rescaled beta distribution: if you let $w=\frac{y}{2\sqrt{n}} + \frac12$ you would get $(n-y^2)^{(n-3)/2}=(4n)^{(n-3)/2} w^{(n-3)/2}(1-w) ^{(n-3)/2}$ which is proportional to the density of a beta distribution

Comment: Many thanks to @Henry. I'm working on standardizing portfolio weighting and this is confusing me. Thanks and I'm new to this community.