# When is $\sum Z_i \sim \sqrt{n} Z_i$?

Tags: random-variable, central-limit-theorem, convolution, sum

If $X_i$ are independently and identically distributed $N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $Y=\sum X_i \sim N(0,n\sigma^2)$, i.e. $\sum X_i  \sim \sqrt{n}X_i$.  That raises two questions:

- Is a zero-mean normal distribution the only such example where the sum of a sample of $n$ iid random variables has the same distribution as the individual components, though rescaled by $\sqrt{n}$?  For distributions with finite variance, the Central Limit Theorem suggests to me this should be the only possibility, but are there examples without a finite variance?
- If the "independent" requirement is removed but identically distributed kept (and perhaps some form of exchangeability), there are other examples, including $Z_i=\frac{X_i}{\sum X_i^2}$ when $X_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ iid (see [a recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552854/derive-the-distribution-of-the-fraction-sumx-i-big-sqrt-sumx-i2)).  What other examples have this property?  Is it possible to state what properties such distribution must have?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution has a bearing on the first question.